# Возникнет ли race condition при параллельном insert postgres

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Есть таблица `create table if not exists objects(
    obj_id bigserial primary key,
    auth_id bigint references users (user_id) on delete cascade,
    path ltree not null,
    text text not null,
    num_likes integer default 0 not null,
    creation_time      timestamptz default current_timestamp not null ,
    modification_time   timestamptz
);`

и триггер

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  insert_object_before_process() RETURNS trigger AS $insert_object_before_process$
    BEGIN
        new.path = new.path || new.obj_id::text;
        return new;
    END;
$insert_object_before_process$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER insert_object_before_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT ON objects
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_object_before_process ()
```

который при добавлении `insert into objects (auth_id, text, path) values (1, 'Привет ребята!', '1');` формирует путь из указанного пользователем + новый serial obj_id. Это нужно чтобы автоматически при ответе на комментарий генерировать новый путь ltree, так как имею древовидную структуру.

1. **Вопрос1:** возникнет ли race condition при параллельной вставке (запрос отменится/запишется 2 раза)
2. **Вопрос2:** Думаю насчет postgres sequence, чтобы не иметь бесполезное поле obj_id,
   но будет nextval потокобезопасным?
3. *Есть ли способ лучше?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> возникнет ли race condition при параллельной вставке (запрос
>   отменится/запишется 2 раза)

Нет. Но `unique` всё равно добавьте к полю, раз нужна уникальность.

> Думаю насчет postgres sequence, чтобы не иметь бесполезное поле
>   obj_id, но будет nextval потокобезопасным?

Вы уже его используете. `bigserial` - это лишь синтаксический сахар, как раз над `create sequence` и `bigint` полем с `default nextval(sequence_name)`. Посмотрите в `pg_dump` этой таблицы.

Сиквенсы специально сделаны нетранзакционными для быстрой и гарантированно уникальной генерации значений. Два `nextval` не могут вернуть одно и то же значение сколь бы быстро не были вызваны.

Comment: Просто obj_id у меня не используется (только при генерации path), но занимает 8 байт на строку, я хотел создать sequence, чтобы не хранить лишнего, так как, насколько я понял, sequence - это таблица, имеющая всего 1 строку. Так ли это?

Comment: ну... кое-что общее есть в src/backend/commands/sequence.c , но в общем sequence - это штука сильно специальная с отдельной логикой чтобы назвать таблицей с одной строкой. Если же говорить именно об объёме данных - то да, весьма разумно удалить поле и из триггера вызывать nextval отдельно-созданного sequence.